# Why aren't request units consistent between retrievals of documents?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In the Azure portal Query Explorer, I'm issuing the following query against my Cosmos DB collection:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE 
    c.DocumentType = 'SalesHistory' 
    And c.DateOfSale >= '2017-04-01' And c.DateOfSale < '2017-04-02'
```

The document returned looks as follows:

```
{
    "DocumentType": "SalesHistory",
    "PartitionKey": "Dealer:9091",
    "RowId": 3387010,
    "DateOfSale": "2017-04-01T10:21:00",
    "InvoiceNumber": 732996,
    "Paymode": "CG",
    "CreditCardRowId": 3,
    "Taxable": false,
    "SalesTax": 0,
    "SalesSubTotal": 290.7,
    "Layaway": false,
    "Pending": false,
    "Void": false,
    "CustomerRowId": 139957,
    "CheckNumber": 0,
    "GiftCertificate": "",
    "UserRowId": 5,
    "SalesDetailRowId": 8907353,
    "BoothNumber": "85",
    "BoothMasterRowId": 2593,
    "DealerRowId": 9091,
    "Description": "Porc Mail Pouch Therm",
    "StockNumber": "40172",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "UnitPrice": 345,
    "DiscountType": "O",
    "DiscountAmount": 54.3,
    "ItemTotal": 290.7,
    "ItemTaxable": 0,
    "ClosedOut": true,
    "CreditCardRate": 2,
    "CreditCardChargeDealer": 1,
    "UserName": "TJones",
    "ClientId": 2,
    "DealerName": "Smith, Larry",
    "CustomerName": "Miller, William",
    "CashReceived": null,
    "id": "20e9a046-6829-4314-bc08-04831838e9b7",
    "_rid": "hSVlAJF0BADGEwAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/hSVlAA==/colls/hSVlAJF0BAA=/docs/hSVlAJF0BADGEwAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"21004e3c-0000-0000-0000-5a60de010000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1516297729
  },
```

The Request Charge to get the first 100 documents is 219.44. The charge for the next 100 documents is 40.96. The charge for the next 100 documents is 41.22. Why is the charge for the first 100 documents 5x more than the next two retrievals of documents?

Comment: can you please share your query metrics for each execution? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics. Likely the first execution needed to perform initial work to compute the index matches.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. - I executed these queries from the portal. I don't see a way to retrieve the query metrics for a query from the portal.

Comment: you'd have to do this with the SDKs. This capability is not yet exposed through the portal. Please email askcosmosdb@microsoft.com if you need help.

Comment: @RandyMinder I tested query operations on the portal and in the sdk, did not reproduce your issue. RUs charge is affected by size of items. Are your document sizes almost the same?

Comment: @JayGong - Check out Aravind's comment to me. There is more to a request charge than just document size. But, to answer your question, yes, the document sizes are very close to the same. Certainly not 5x smaller.

Comment: @RandyMinder Is this happening by chance or always? Have you tried to create new collection then import data to test?